# Strange calculation problem in C multiply by 1.2 fails

Tags: c, casting

I have this c code, where i need to calculate a dobule from a long.

```
double result;
long t2_value;

t2_value = 72;
result = t2_value * 1.2;
```

Now this code crashes at "result = t2_value * 1.2;" only with the error "Vector 0000000006".

Here is the strange thing, if i replace

```
result = t2_value * 1.2;
```

with

```
result = 72 * 1.2;
```

evything works just as it should, i have tryed type casting t2_value as an double

```
result = ((double)t2_value * 1.2);
```

or making it an int istead of a long, but nothing helps.

All the code, see the main method
    /*! \file
     *      \brief The first user program - 
     *
     */

```
#include <scwrapper.h>


long thread_1_empty_semaphore_handle;
long thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle;
long thread_1_full_semaphore_handle;
long thread_2_empty_semaphore_handle;
long thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle;
long thread_2_full_semaphore_handle;

int debug;

long value_thread_1;
long value_thread_2;


long send_port;

void thread_1(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        long value;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_1_full_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        // Generating some random number here and save it in value_thread_1
        value_thread_1 = 91;
        if(debug == 1) prints("Writing thread 1!\n");

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_1_empty_semaphore_handle))
            break;
    }
    terminate();
}
void thread_2(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        long value;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_2_full_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        // Generating some random number here and save it in value_thread_1
        value_thread_2 = 72;
        if(debug == 1) prints("Writing thread 2!\n");

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle))
            break;

        if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_2_empty_semaphore_handle))
            break;
    }
    terminate();
}

int create_thread_1()
{
    if(debug == 1)
        prints("Creating thread 1!\n");
    register long  thread_stack;
    thread_1_empty_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(16);
    if (thread_1_empty_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_1_full_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(0);
    if (thread_1_full_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(1);
    if (thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_stack=alloc(4096, 0);
    if (0 >= thread_stack)
        return -1;
    if (ALL_OK != createthread(thread_1, thread_stack+4096))
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
long read_tread_1()
{
    long value = 0;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_1_empty_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    value = value_thread_1;
    if(debug == 1)
        prints("Reading thread 1!\n");

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_1_mutex_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_1_full_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    return value;
}

int create_thread_2()
{
    if(debug == 1)
        prints("Creating thread 2!\n");
    register long  thread_stack;
    thread_2_empty_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(16);
    if (thread_2_empty_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_2_full_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(0);
    if (thread_2_full_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle=createsemaphore(1);
    if (thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle<0)
        return -1;
    thread_stack=alloc(4096, 0);
    if (0 >= thread_stack)
        return -1;
    if (ALL_OK != createthread(thread_2, thread_stack+4096))
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
long read_tread_2()
{
    long value = 0;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_2_empty_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoredown(thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    value = value_thread_2;
    if(debug == 1)
        prints("Reading thread 2!\n");

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_2_mutex_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    if (ALL_OK != semaphoreup(thread_2_full_semaphore_handle))
        return -1;

    return value;
}

int send_message(double message)
{
    struct message msg;

    if(debug == 1)
        prints("Canculation message");
    // We are multiplying the integer with 1000, and thorws all the decimals away
    long temp = (long)(message * 1000.0);
    msg.quad_0 = temp;
    msg.quad_1 = 0;
    msg.quad_2=0;
    msg.quad_3=0;
    msg.quad_4=0;
    msg.quad_5=0;
    msg.quad_6=0;
    msg.quad_7=0;

    prints("0: ");
    printhex(msg.quad_0);
    prints("\n");
    prints("1: ");
    printhex(msg.quad_1);
    prints("\n");

    if (ALL_OK != send(send_port, &msg))
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
void administrat_medicin(double amount)
{
}

void
    main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    debug = 0;
    long my_pid = getpid();

    create_thread_1();
    create_thread_2();

    /* Launch instances of program_1 */
    if (ALL_OK != createprocess(1))
    {
        if(debug == 1)
            prints("Unable to launch program 1 in a new process\n");
        debugger();
    }

    // Finding a send port
    send_port = findport(0,1);
    if (send_port < 0)
    {
        if(debug == 1)
            prints("process 1: finding a send port in process 0 failed\n");
        terminate();
    }

    /* This is the producer. */
    long t1_value; // Puls
    long t2_value; // Blod sugar
    double result;
    double ration = 1.2;
    while(1)
    {
        t1_value = read_tread_1();
        if(-1 == t1_value)
        {
            if(debug == 1)
                prints("Error reading t1");
            break;
        }

        t2_value = read_tread_2();
        if(-1 == t2_value)
        {
            if(debug == 1)
                prints("Error reading t2");
            break;
        }

        // If there are no date yet, no point in sending it
        // This will also skip if there are no pulse
        if(t1_value > 0 && t2_value > 0)
        {
            // Calculate the medicine to give.
            prints("Calculating\n");
            result = (t2_value * ration);
            prints("Result: ");
            printhex(result);
            prints("\n");

            if(debug == 1)
                prints("Sending message\n");
            if(-1 == send_message(result))
            {
                if(debug == 1)
                prints("Message send failed");
            }
            if(debug == 1)
                prints("Message sendt");
        }
    }
}
```

Make file

```
# The following line holds compiler options
CFLAGS = -fno-exceptions -fno-common -Isrc/include

# Do not change the following line. You will not be able to compile without it
PREFIX := "${PWD}/../../support_software/bin/bin"

bochs_boot: boot/kernel
    ${PREFIX}/genext2fs -b 1440 -d boot bochs_stuff/b.img
    (cd bochs_stuff; nice -20 ${PREFIX}/bochs)

kernel: boot/kernel

src/include/scwrapper.h: src/include/sysdefines.h

src/kernel/kernel.h: src/include/sysdefines.h

boot/kernel: objects/kernel/boot32.o objects/kernel/boot64.o objects/kernel/enter.o src/kernel/kernel_link.ld objects/program_0/executable.o objects/program_1/executable.o objects/program_2/executable.o binary_kernel/binary_kernel.o
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-ld --no-warn-mismatch -Tsrc/kernel/binary_kernel_link.ld -o boot/kernel objects/kernel/boot32.o objects/kernel/boot64.o objects/kernel/enter.o binary_kernel/binary_kernel.o objects/program_0/executable.o objects/program_1/executable.o objects/program_2/executable.o

objects/kernel/boot32.o: src/kernel/boot32.s
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-as --32 -o objects/kernel/boot32.o src/kernel/boot32.s

objects/kernel/boot64.o: src/kernel/boot64.s
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-as --64 -o objects/kernel/boot64.o src/kernel/boot64.s

objects/kernel/enter.o: src/kernel/enter.s
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-as --64 -o objects/kernel/enter.o src/kernel/enter.s

objects/program_startup_code/startup.o: src/program_startup_code/startup.s
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-as --64 -o objects/program_startup_code/startup.o src/program_startup_code/startup.s

objects/program_0/main.o: src/program_0/main.c src/include/scwrapper.h
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-gcc -fPIE -m64 $(CFLAGS) -c -O3 -o objects/program_0/main.o src/program_0/main.c

objects/program_0/executable: objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_0/main.o
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-ld -static -Tsrc/program_startup_code/program_link.ld -o objects/program_0/executable objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_0/main.o

objects/program_0/executable.o: objects/program_0/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-strip objects/program_0/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-objcopy  -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 --set-section-flags .data=alloc,contents,load,readonly,data objects/program_0/executable objects/program_0/executable.o

objects/program_1/main.o: src/program_1/main.c src/include/scwrapper.h
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-gcc -fPIE -m64 $(CFLAGS) -c -O3 -o objects/program_1/main.o src/program_1/main.c

objects/program_1/executable: objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_1/main.o
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-ld -static -Tsrc/program_startup_code/program_link.ld -o objects/program_1/executable objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_1/main.o

objects/program_1/executable.o: objects/program_1/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-strip objects/program_1/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-objcopy  -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 --set-section-flags .data=alloc,contents,load,readonly,data objects/program_1/executable objects/program_1/executable.o

objects/program_2/main.o: src/program_2/main.c src/include/scwrapper.h
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-gcc -fPIE -m64 $(CFLAGS) -c -O3 -o objects/program_2/main.o src/program_2/main.c

objects/program_2/executable: objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_2/main.o
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-ld -static -Tsrc/program_startup_code/program_link.ld -o objects/program_2/executable objects/program_startup_code/startup.o objects/program_2/main.o

objects/program_2/executable.o: objects/program_2/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-strip objects/program_2/executable
    ${PREFIX}/x86_64-pc-elf-objcopy  -I binary -O elf32-i386 -B i386 --set-section-flags .data=alloc,contents,load,readonly,data objects/program_2/executable objects/program_2/executable.o

clean:
    -rm -rf objects
    -rm boot/kernel
    -rm bochs_stuff/b.img
    mkdir objects
    mkdir objects/kernel
    mkdir objects/program_startup_code
    mkdir objects/program_0
    mkdir objects/program_1
    mkdir objects/program_2

compile: boot/kernel
```

Here is prints and printhex
void

```
prints(const char* string)
{
 /* Loop until we have found the null character. */
 while(1)
 {
  register const char curr = *string++;

  if (curr)
  {
   outb(0xe9, curr);
  }
  else
  {
   return;
  }
 }
}

void
printhex(const register long value)
{
 const static char hex_helper[16]="0123456789abcdef";
 register int      i;

 /* Print each character of the hexadecimal number. This is a very inefficient
    way of printing hexadecimal numbers. It is, however, very compact in terms
    of the number of source code lines. */
 for(i=15; i>=0; i--)
 {
  outb(0xe9, hex_helper[(value>>(i*4))&15]);
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this really the exact code you have trouble with? You are declaring `long t2_value` twice, which should give a compiler error. Have you tried this exact code snippet with the described results?

Comment: You need to post the actual code *and* state what compiler etc you're using.

Comment: I'm not sure, as i normaly don't do c code, but i think the compiler is called "bochs"

Comment: That's a lot of code, and it's still not compileable. I'm guessing the error is somewhere else, like one of your threads or the `printhex` function.

Comment: No that is not the problem, as it gets to Calculating, but not "Result:"! it is at the code "result = (t2_value * ration);" it fails

Comment: Bochs is an x86 PC emulator, not a compiler - what is your actual programming environment, and what is the target ?

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure, i am normaly a C# programmer and have almost no expirence with C, we are just using the make files the teacher gave us. The tast i'm trying to create is a soft real-time system, that reads the blood sugar of a diabetes patient and calculate how much medicin the patient needs. This code need to run on as past of an operating system, our teacher made. I will include the make file in the first question if that can help.

Comment: The thought of doing floating point math in kernel code makes me feel all squick...

Comment: Your observations are drawing you to the wrong conclusion.  The observation that it displays one string and not another, does not mean that the code between those two outputs is where it is failing.  For two reasons: (1) Text output may be buffered and may not be output when you think it is. (2) You have multiple concurrent threads, the error may be in another thread.  You would be better off using a thread-aware debugger to resolve this rather than output strings.  Since prints() is not a standard function, and not shown, there is no way of telling what it does.

Comment: I have added prints and printhex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's comment may have hit upon something.  Since this is not a standard environment, do you know that floating point operations are even supported?  And are they really necessary or advisable?  You will most probably get acceptable results from:

```
long result;     // integer type
long t2_value;

t2_value = 72;
result = ((t2_value * 10) * 12) / 100 ; // result = 86
```

If you need more significant figures then for example:

```
result = ((t2_value * 100) * 120) / 1000 ; // result = 864
```

here `result` is a value in 1/10ths of the real world unit.

Comment: Thank you this workes like  charm, you must be right that the system dose not support floating point operations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hazarding a guess here, but I'm pretty sure SSE instructions are not allowed in most kernels (If I remember correctly there may be a config option to allow it, though).  Even when not using vectors of data, compilers will often use the SSE extensions to do floating point computations.  Try adding `-mno-sse` (or whatever the equivalent is to your compiler) to your Makefile flags.